# Call CreateView from DetailView

Tags: django, django-views

In url.py I have this lines:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/*$', ViewPage.as_view(), name='view'), 
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/__create$', CreatePage.as_view(), name='create'),
```

and in views.py:

```
class ViewPage(DetailView):
    model = Page
    slug_field = 'url'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(self, 'object', None):
            return self.object
        return super(ViewPage, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.object = self.get_object()
        except Http404:
            # return custom template
            return reverse('create', kwargs=kwargs)
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

class CreatePage(CreateView):
    model = Page
    slug_field = 'url'
```

Main goal of this code its call CreatePage if object not exist. 
But on line " reverse('create', kwargs=kwargs)" I got error :
'str' object has no attribute 'get'

I understand that I can not properly convey the variable kwargs.

So my questions:

```
1) May be other way to do what I want?
2) Or how to properly pass kwargs?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's helpful to know this error is coming from your view function, not `reverse`. Therefore you have a URL, it's just not formatted correctly.

A django view must return an `HttpResponse` type or subclass, you can't return a string. You can return a string in an response `HttpResponse("my string")` but not a string directly.

In your case, return an `HttpResponseRedirect`

```
return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(...))
```

Comment: Thank you Yuji. I rewrite to string : return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create', kwargs=kwargs)). And all works.

Comment: @DmitryMaevskiy hey dmitry, glad it helped! Please accept answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use django's shortcut redirect function.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import redirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect # <---

def foo(request, *a, **kw):
    return redirect(reverse("bar", kw=kw)) # <---
```

I personally enjoy a function based style.